# identifierForVendor for UUIDString returns null

Tags: ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, iphone-5

I have implemented push notification in my iPhone app and for device registration i used following code in the app.

```
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

Above code works fine in the most of the devices. However, recently in some iPhone 5s devices with iOS 7.1 it returns null and due to this app crashes.

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I am also having the same issue.

Comment: @iOSMonster : i didn't get exact solution but as i believe this is happen because of device name with char ' (Apostrophes).

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor);

> If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens, for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user has unlocked the device.

This can happen for instance with a VoIP app that starts by the system on restart to allow the app to listen for incoming calls.

Answer (score -3):

As this is now a old question,i also faced the same issues.So I felt to answer here for others,if they come a across this issues.

```
NSString *uid=[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
NSLog(@"udd:%@",uid);
```

Comment: That property doesn't exist on modern iOS versions.